# Imagine slicing a polygon like a pizza haphazardly, how would you find the largest slice?

Tags: java, graph

I have a polygon that have been divided up with multiple lines, creating new smaller polygons that make up the whole. How would I go about finding the slice with the largest area?

Imagine something like this: [sliced polygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jelfp.png) green points are vertices, lines intersect creating more vertices, looking for the largest yellow marked area.

I figured this could be solved by generating a directed graph in order to define each unique shape. I can't come up with a way to link all vertices correctly though.

All vertices and edge lengths are either given or calculated with these methods.

```
public static double calcDistanceBetweenPoints(Point a, Point b){
        return Math.sqrt((b.y - a.y) * (b.y - a.y) + (b.x - a.x) * (b.x - a.x));
}
```

```
public static Point findIntersection(Point A, Point B, Point C, Point D){
    // Line AB represented as a1x + b1y = c1
    double a1 = B.y - A.y;
    double b1 = A.x - B.x;
    double c1 = a1*(A.x) + b1*(A.y);
  
    // Line CD represented as a2x + b2y = c2
    double a2 = D.y - C.y;
    double b2 = C.x - D.x;
    double c2 = a2*(C.x)+ b2*(C.y);
  
    double determinant = a1*b2 - a2*b1;
  
    if (determinant == 0)
    {
        // The lines are parallel
        return new Point(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    }
    else
    {
        double x = (b2*c1 - b1*c2)/determinant;
        double y = (a1*c2 - a2*c1)/determinant;
        return new Point(x, y);
    }
}
```

Data collected from the System.in input stream looks something like this:

```
n m
x1 y1
x.. y...
xn yn
x11 y11 x21 y21
x.. y.. x.. y..
x1m y1m x2m y2m
```

So I get all the starting and ending points for each line from the input.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `I can't come up with a way to link all vertices correctly though.` - So the actual question is how to ***create connections*** in the ***Graph***, right? Can provide a code snippet illustrating how you're getting the *Points* which correspond to the vertices of the *Polygon*, and *Points* denoting the *slicing Lines*?

Comment: So the question is from a leetcode type site I'm using to practice problems. All the data is read from the System.in inputstream. See the edit of the mainpost of how its formatted.

Comment: Input without description isn't very clear, which of these coordinates form slicing lines, and which represent the vertices of the Polygon? Can you post the link? Since you're asking how to link vertices in the Graph, a bit more context would be helpful.